# When you type #include <iostream>, are you including a template?

Tags: c++

I was just wondering because if you type `#include <map>`, you're including the map template.

Comment: Did you try looking in that header?

Comment: @CarlNorum: The first lines were probably "Viewer discretion advised" ;) Seriously, it's usually not readable by mortals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angle brackets (`< >`) just tell the compiler how it should look for the file (as opposed to quotes `" "`). The contents of that file is irrelevant, it can contain *whatever*.

---

The angle brackets in `#include <map>` and `template <...> map` have no correlation whatsoever. The syntax just uses the same characters for completely different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It includes a header file. It may contain templates, but might also contain only `#define` statements, function prototypes, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Why do we use the angle brackets then, instead of #include "iostream.hh"?

Comment: They mean different things, both implementation defined.  If the `""` search fails, the implementation falls back to the `<>` case.  In most implementations, `""` searches the current directory and `<>` searches the system header directory.  Check out the C++ spec section 16.2.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasons for the choice of characters is that neither `<>` nor `"` are commonly used in filenames, so they make very good characters to delimit filenames.

Using similar logic, neither `<` nor `>` appears in C++ identifiers, so the characters can be used to delimit template arguments.

So, while the logic for the choice of `<>` is similar, the actual names delimited are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

At least given the way most current compilers deal with templates, yes. Specifically, most compilers need to have "seen" the definition of the a template before they will let you instantiate that template.

Up until C++03, there was (theoretically) an `export` keyword that would eliminate that requirement, but most compilers never implemented it, and even the minuscule number that did, didn't use it for most libraries like this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++11 standard, the header contains  this

```
#include <ios>
#include <streambuf>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

namespace std {

    extern istream cin;
    extern ostream cout;
    extern ostream cerr;
    extern ostream clog;

    extern wistream wcin;
    extern wostream wcout;
    extern wostream wcerr;
    extern wostream wclog;

}
```

which includes a lot of templates.

The earlier standard wasn't that explicit on exactly what headers `<iostream>` must include, just that it should declare the streams.